# Is there a way to not have to specify the user when connecting with psycogp2?

Tags: python, psycopg2

So just passing in the host and db name and not having to specify the user like:

`host=blabla.co port=7000 dbname=ff_db`

instead of:

`host=blabla.co port=7000 dbname=ff_db user=some_user`

The `.pgpass` file already has the user specified so I feel passing this in is redundant.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You have a problem with specifying the user? Give more details

Comment: for security reasons i think it's best not to have to specify the user

Comment: That's why you should create a user which can access only the given DB, otherwise if you connected without a user it will be worse for the security.

Comment: The point is not having to specify the username because it's in the `.pgpass` file already...

Comment: I think, you can connect with unix socket. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192134/connect-to-a-db-using-psycopg2-without-password you can check this, it should be same with the username

Comment: Docs are wonderful: [psycoog2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html) which leads to [envars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html). Almost like someone had already thought of this.

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pg_service-conf-the-forgotten-config-file/ one better. Though I don't know if you were being sarcastic or trying to help... if it's the former, you need to find better things to do in life. If it's the latter, then thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the env var `PGUSER`. See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) for all the options.